# Hang in sscanf with APP_STL=c++_shared when running on Android 5.0 (Lollipop)

Tags: android, android-ndk, libc++

If you link with c++_shared (LLVM's libc++) and your app uses `pthread_create` at least once, any calls to `sscanf` (after `pthread_create`) will hang in `pthread_mutex_lock`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is frivolous use of 'struct FILE' internals in Google's "android_support" auxiliary library. It's likely this structure was changed in Android 5.0 Bionic.

Since NDK r10d eliminates android_support's buggy `sscanf` implementation (in [commit 47e68e84ee043436387a053c1cd47b97cabbb8ca](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk.git/+/47e68e84ee043436387a053c1cd47b97cabbb8ca)), it is no longer affected. If you must use an older NDK, apply [commit 47e68e84ee043436387a053c1cd47b97cabbb8ca](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk.git/+/47e68e84ee043436387a053c1cd47b97cabbb8ca) to it as an interim fix.

Simple reproduction follows.

Application.mk:

```
APP_ABI := armeabi
APP_STL := c++_shared
APP_PIE := true
```

Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := test
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := test.cpp
include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

test.cpp:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void* threadproc(void *) {
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    pthread_t thread;
    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, threadproc, NULL); // causes __isthreaded to be set
    unsigned int foo;
    sscanf("12345", "%u", &foo); // locks up by calling Bionic's flockfile on its own fake FLE
}
```